Non-decimated wavelet packet transform
I want to perform a non-decimated wavelet packet tranform in Python using PyWavelets. Is there a way to do this? If not how can I implement it manually?
I tried to use pywt.swt with level=1 and just use it on every set of coefficients but then I am missing the upsampling of the low-pass and high pass filters when doing a multi-level decomposition (level>1).
Any help is appreciated.
